# Why do I get an undefined method 'have' error when running Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I recently upgraded to Rails 4 and everything works fine except for my Rspec tests.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Invoice do

  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:activated_user)
    person = FactoryGirl.create(:person, :user => @user, :company => nil)
    @project = FactoryGirl.create(:project, :user => @user, :person_ids => [person.id], :invoice_recipient_id => person.id)
  end

  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:invoice, :project => @project, :user => @user)).to be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a number" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:invoice, :project => @project, :user => @user, :number => nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:number)
  end

end
```

When running these tests I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:invoice, :project => @project, :user => @user, :number => nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:number)
NoMethodError:
undefined method `have' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Invoice_2:0x009ge29360d910>
# ./spec/models/invoice_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

I googled it already but nothing came up. The `have` method is actually fairly standard in Rspec and I can't see why it shouldn't work.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Try passing a block to expect and not an instance (i.e., expect { })

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't change anything. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: OK, posted some more details above.

Comment: As for me everything is correct (exactly as official examples). If I were you I would try to check this case `expect(Invoice.new).to have...` (use your class instead of Factory - do you have the same error?). Then try to check version and maybe update gem rspec-rails. Another idea: do you use spork, zeus or smth like this? Maybe smth is wrong in `spec_helper.rb`

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: Sorry about that, just removed the first two lines. Now it looks exactly like in my app.

Comment: I just ran `rails g rspec:install` again to update my `spec_helper.rb` file. Then tried `expect(Invoice.new).to have(1).errors_on(:number)`. But it gives me the exact same error as before.

Comment: OK, solved and posted below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `have` family of matchers was deprecated in RSpec 2.99 and has been moved to a separate [rspec-collection_matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers) gem as of RSpec 3.0. This is discussed in https://rspec.info/blog/2013/11/rspec-2-99-and-3-0-betas-have-been-released/, which also gives the suggested approach to migrating to 3.0. Specifically, it recommends installing/using RSpec 2.99 in order to see the deprecation messages associated with items that were removed/moved in 3.0.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, Peter! Strange that I was unable to find this myself. I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: And thank you for reporting your problem. It turns out the removal in 3.00 was mistakenly omitted from the 3.0 beta 1 change log. After reporting it, they made a retroactive update to that section, per https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/commit/d71bff4e81059494d9fdc09ccf5694164dbc038e#comments

Comment: why do they separate it? Is it not recommended not use "have"?

Comment: The primary maintainer felt they were confusing, as he discussed in http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2013/07/the-plan-for-rspec-3#comment-968188440

Answer (score 5):

In the latest versions of rspec "have" being deprecated, but you still can use it via [rspec-collection_matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers) gem.

```
# Gemfile
...
gem 'rspec-collection_matchers', group: :test
...

# spec/spec_helper.rb
...
require 'rspec/collection_matchers'
....
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it.

I had the wrong version number in my Gemfile.

Before:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta'
```

After:

```
gem 'rspec-rails'
```