# When I run the test “ rspec item_container_spec.rb ”In the console, I'll get a warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
  it 'add items into the container' do
    item1 = Item.new('kettle', price: 200)
    item2 = Item.new('kettle', price: 300)
    @box.add_item(item1)
    @box.add_item(item2)
    @box.items.should have(2).items
  end
```

This team might mistake? " @box.items.should have(2).items  " .
In the console, I'll get a warning

```
**E:\work\storeapp\spec>rspec item_container_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) ItemContainer add items into the container
     Failure/Error: @box.items.should have(2).items
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `have' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ItemContainer:0x2419908>
     # ./item_container_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0 seconds (files took 0.23234 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./item_container_spec.rb:22 # ItemContainer add items into the container**
```

where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that you have installed rspec 3.0.

The `have` family of matchers was deprecated in RSpec 2.99 and has been moved to a separate rspec-collection_matchers gem as of RSpec 3.0.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406625/why-do-i-get-an-undefined-method-have-error-when-running-rspec).

Comment: I'm just learning and I do not really understand.
I want to remove my " rspec -v 3.2.2 " and install " RSpec 2.99.0.beta1 " ?

Comment: Change the version of rspec in your gemfile then run bundle install in your terminal.

Comment: I think it would better to update the test rather than use an old version of RSpec: `@box.items.size.should == 2`

Comment: @AndyWaite , I ran the test :  @box.items.size.should == 2 , and there was an error :

Deprecation Warnings:

Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` with
`config.expect_with(:rspec) { |c| c.syntax = :should }` instead. Called from E:/work/storeapp/spec/item_container_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'.

Comment: @Vitalik Andrysha : if you chose to keep rspec 3, then you will have to change your whole test. You should use expect().to instead of ().should. Look at the documentation of rspec.

Comment: @VitalikAndrysha in Ruby, a warning is not an error. The test should still have passed. But as @Chambeur suggests, you should use the newer `expect` syntax to avoid this happening.

Comment: @Chambeur how to replace the version I set earlier, and I installed version of rspec-3.2.0 ? ____________

E:\work\storeapp\spec>gem install rspec 2.14
Fetching: rspec-3.2.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rspec-3.2.0
Parsing documentation for rspec-3.2.0
Installing ri documentation for rspec-3.2.0
Done installing documentation for rspec after 0 seconds
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '2.14' (>= 0) in any repository
1 gem installed

Comment: @VitalikAndrysha maybe the version you're seeking is so deprecated that it's not available anymore. As AndyWaite said, try to upgrade your code instead of downgrade your stack. And if you plan to ask on SO everytime you have an error, you gonna have a bad time.